Error message booting Ubuntu server on Oracle VM
I got these error messages booting up Ubuntu server on Oracle VM.
[drm] *ERROR* vmwgfx seems to be running on an unsupported hypervisor. 
[drm] *ERROR* This configuration is likely broken.
[drm] *ERROR* Please switch to a supported graphics device to avoid problems. 

What should I do?

hi @sylvester as error message say, you could try switching  graphics device by going to: Settings (for the VM you have created) > Display > Graphics Controller, and try a different graphics. Most likely you'll have 3 options: VMSVGA, VBoxSVGA and VBOxVGA. Thanks.
